# Flink Kafka Sink org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException ERROR

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

version flink(1.11.3), kafka(2.1.1)

My flink datapipeline is kafka(source) -> flink -> kafka(sink).

When I submit job first, it works well.
but after jobmanager or taskmanagers fail, if they restarted, they occur exception

> 2020-12-31 10:35:23.831 [objectOperator -> Sink: objectSink (1/1)] WARN  o.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer  - Encountered error org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidTxnStateException: The producer attempted a transactional operation in an invalid state. while recovering transaction KafkaTransactionState [transactionalId=objectOperator -> Sink: objectSink-bcabd9b643c47ab46ace22db2e1285b6-3, producerId=14698, epoch=7]. Presumably this transaction has been already committed before
> 2020-12-31 10:35:23.919 [userOperator -> Sink: userSink (1/1)] WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task  - userOperator -> Sink: userSink (1/1) (2a5a171aa335f444740b4acfc7688d7c) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidPidMappingException: The producer attempted to use a producer id which is not currently assigned to its transactional id.
> 2020-12-31 10:35:24.131 [objectOperator -> Sink: objectSink (1/1)] WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task  - objectOperator -> Sink: objectSink (1/1) (07fe747a81b31e016e88ea6331b31433) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: Attempted to write a non-default producerId at version 1

I don't know why this error occurs.

my kafka producer code

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", servers);
        props.setProperty("transaction.timeout.ms", "30000");
        FlinkKafkaProducer<CountModel> producer = new FlinkKafkaProducer<CountModel>(
                topic,((record, timestamp) -> new ProducerRecord<>(
                        topic
                        , Longs.toByteArray(record.getUserInKey())
                        , JsonUtils.toJsonBytes(record))), props, FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE);
```

I don't think it's a version issue.
It seems that no one has experienced the same error as me

Answer (score 0):

Each Producer is assigned a unique PID when it is initialized. This PID is transparent to the application and is not exposed to the user at all. For a given PID, the sequence number will increase from 0, and each Topic-Partition will have an independent sequence number. When the Producer sends data, it will identify a sequence number for each msg, and the Server will use this to verify whether the data is duplicated. The PID here is globally unique, and a new PID will be assigned after the Producer is restarted after a failure. This is also one of the reasons why idempotence cannot be achieved across sessions.

If you resume from savepoint, the previous producerId will be used, and a new session will generate 1000 new producerIds (these id runs through the entire session, equivalent to the default value), so it will be non-default